# auto update python library

Tags: python, git

In Windows OS, I have a python library in a git repository.

Some users, on different computers, use the library (scripts, etc), for routine tasks. But they have no knowledge of python or programming, only use the scripts.

when I push a new commit to repository, how they can get automatically update of library ?

Answer (score 1):

What OS are you using?  Linux has a utility called cron that lets you schedule routine tasks.  You could tell cron on each computer to run `cd repo && git pull` every hour.

You might also consider doing something with a git hook:
http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Answer (score 0):

If each user has cloned the library repo to his `site-packages`, it is possible to schedule a task on their systems, which will do `git pull` with fixed frequency.

[Here](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-create-task-basic-task-wizard) is a tutorial on how to setup a scheduled task on Winodws 7.